# How to write SQL query with many % wildcard characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a coloumn in Sql Server table as:

```
companystring = {"CompanyId":0,"CompanyType":1,"CompanyName":"Test     
215","TradingName":"Test     215","RegistrationNumber":"Test 
215","Email":"test215@tradeslot.com","Website":"Test    
215","DateStarted":"2012","CompanyValidationErrors":[],"CompanyCode":null}
```

I want to query the column to search for

```
companyname like '%CompanyName":"%test 2%","%'
```

I want to know if I'm querying correctly, because for some search string it does not yield the proper result. Could anyone please help me with this?

Edit: I have removed the format bold

Comment: your companyname in the string is `"**CompanyName**"`, yet the query you gave us is incorrect.  the sample query should be `%"**CompanyName**":"%test 2%", "%**'`  Please fix your sample to remove the bolding characters (if that's what they are).

Comment: You may get some help with this but in the name of god, fix your database!

Comment: Could you help us out here? What is "the proper result"?

Answer (score 2):

`%` is a special character that means a wildcard. If you want to find the actual character inside a string, you need to escape it.

```
DECLARE @d TABLE(id INT, s VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @d VALUES(1,'foo%bar'),(2,'fooblat');

SELECT id, s FROM @d WHERE s LIKE 'foo[%]%'; -- returns only 1

SELECT id, s FROM @d WHERE s LIKE 'foo%'; -- returns both 1 and 2
```

Comment: [%] are square bracket used to escape the special character ? Will it escape only one % character in the string or any number of % characters ? like if I have a string Foo%Ball%Something

Comment: @MuhammedAli it's only escaping it in that place.

Comment: I don't believe he is actually wanting to search for the % character.

Comment: @Timothy maybe, but I am having an extremely hard time interpreting what he does want. All we know is he doesn't know if he's querying correctly because it doesn't return the proper result. But what is the proper result? Do you know? I sure don't.

Comment: My guess (as per my answer) is that he is wanting to search a column that contains JSON for a property that contains a value. BTW love your work, I've found heaps of your answers helpful

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your platform, you might be able to use some combination of regular expressions and/or lambda expressions which are built into its main libraries.  For example, .NET has LINQ , which is a powerful tool that abstracts querying and which provides leveraging for searches.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have JSON data stored in a column called "companystring". If you want to search within the JSON data from SQL things get very tricky.

I would suggest you look at doing some extra processing at insert/update to expose the properties of the JSON you want to search on.

If you search in the way you describe, you would actually need to use Regular Expressions or something else to make it reliable.

In your example you say you want to search for:

```
companystring like '%CompanyName":"%test 2%","%'
```

I understand this as searching inside the JSON for the string "test 2" somewhere inside the "CompanyName" property. Unfortunately this would also return results where "test 2" was found in any other property after "CompanyName", such as the following:

```
-- formatted for readability
companystring = '{
    "CompanyId":0,
    "CompanyType":1,
    "CompanyName":"Test Something 215",
    "TradingName":"Test 215",
    "RegistrationNumber":"Test 215",
    "Email":"test215@tradeslot.com",
    "Website":"Test 215",
    "DateStarted":"2012",
    "CompanyValidationErrors":[],
    "CompanyCode":null}'
```

Even though "test 2" isn't in the CompanyName, it is in the text following it (TradingName), which is also followed by the string `","` so it would meet your search criteria.

Another option would be to create a view that exposes the value of CompanyName using a column defined as follows:

```
LEFT(
    SUBSTRING(companystring, CHARINDEX('"CompanyName":"', companystring) + LEN('"CompanyName":"'), LEN(companystring)),
    CHARINDEX('"', SUBSTRING(companystring, CHARINDEX('"CompanyName":"', companystring) + LEN('"CompanyName":"'), LEN(companystring))) - 1
) AS CompanyName
```

Then you could query that view using `WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%test 2%'` and it would work, although performance could be an issue.

The logic of the above is to get everything after `"CompanyName":":`

```
SUBSTRING(companystring, CHARINDEX('"CompanyName":"', companystring) + LEN('"CompanyName":"'), LEN(companystring))
```

Up to but not including the first `"` in the sub-string (which is why it is used twice).